# Find Unique characters between Two column comparison

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I want to compare column1 and column2 and get the unique values causing difference to be detected from column1 . So in this case, I should get answer to be 'Residence - Location', '-12', 'NAN' and 'NA' for empty.Its comparing first column to second one

Also, can we create and store the result in another column?

```
Result
index   column1         column2                     diff
1.      Admission Date  Residence - Location        Residence - Location
2.      Malnutrition    Malnutrition-12             -12
3.      TB              NAN                         NAN
4.      Anaemia         NA                          NA
```

Code can be in either R or Python. I dont mind

```
def FindDifference(Row):
    x = Row['column1']
    y = Row['column2']

    Difference = ""
    if pd.isnull(y) or y=="nan" or y=="NA":
        return NaN
    if len(x) <= len(y):
        for i in y:
            if i not in x:
                Difference += str(i)
    else:
        for i in x:
            if i not in y:
                Difference += str(i)
    return Difference

ReadDataT = Final_df[['column1','column2']] 
ReadDataT['diff']= ReadDataT.apply(lambda x: FindDifference(x),axis=1)
ReadDataT
```

The problem with this code is it is comparing each character between the two and giving result of characters which are not only in both columns...Say like first row is giving  'RC-Lc' as the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, we can use `sub` along with `mapply`

```
df$diff <- mapply(function(x, y) sub(x, "", y), df$column1, df$column2)

df
#  index        column1              column2                 diff
#1     1 Admission Date Residence - Location Residence - Location
#2     2   Malnutrition      Malnutrition-12                  -12
#3     3             TB                  NAN                  NAN
#4     4        Anaemia                 <NA>                 <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr); library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(diff = str_remove(column2, column1))

  index        column1              column2                 diff
1     1 Admission Date Residence - Location Residence - Location
2     2   Malnutrition      Malnutrition-12                  -12
3     3             TB                  NAN                  NAN
4     4        Anaemia                 <NA>                 <NA>
```

---

Edit: Same w/o `dplyr`

```
df$diff = stringr::str_remove(df$column2, df$column1)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

For Python:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex = True)
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['column2'].replace(x['column1'], '').strip(), axis = 1)
df = df.replace('', np.nan, regex = True)
```

Output:

```
          column1               column2                  diff
0  Admission Date  Residence - Location  Residence - Location
1    Malnutrition       Malnutrition-12                   -12
2              TB                   NaN                   NaN
3         Anaemia                   NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: getting this error based on data I have "('Column11', 'occurred at index 0')"

Comment: Where is column11 coming from, have to see the whole thing then!

Comment: Its column1 sorry...I have sample dataset here https://github.com/livingstone90/Compare-CSV/blob/master/DiffbCol.csv   with old columns and new columns with prefix NEW_column name....You can try the code on columns like Branching Logic and New_Branching Logic. You will get that error. Thanks

Comment: Which is your column1 and column2 here?

Comment: Column1 is 'Branching Logic(show field only if)' then column2 is 'New_Branching Logic(show field only if)'     on that data

Comment: It also looks like some of your rows in the New_Branching are shifted up or down by a few rows. It looks difficult even for reading to understand how the code should be.

Comment: Its a data dictionary but feel free to use two columns that you understand..The columns are organized in 2 pairs, Old and New one...so you can choose two columns that you find okey. they are close to each other Old and New one

Comment: Sorry, but the file isnt helping me, it seems strange and odd and am not able to quite figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196896/discussion-between-livingstone-and-ankur-sinha).